# How to minimize the next functional using the Pontryagin Maximum Principle?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

Best regards,

I am asked to minimize the next functional

$T(v)=\int_{A}^{B}\frac{dx}{v(x)}$,

with $v\neq 0\text{ and } v\in V$, where $V=\{v\in C([A,B]):v(A)=v(B)=0\}$.

If we assume that there exists $v^*$  that minimizes the functional, then $v^*$ satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equation.

Euler-Lagrange Equation: $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'})=0$.

If $L=\frac{1}{v},v\neq 0$

$y=v\Rightarrow \frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=-\frac{1}{v^2},$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}=0\Rightarrow\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'})=0,$

then $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'})=-\frac{1}{v^2}-0=0\Rightarrow \frac{1}{v^2}=0,$ which is impossible, then must resort to the Principle of Maximum of Pontryagin.

How can I use the Pontryagin maximum principle in this case and I have also been told that the optimal $v$ is reached at point $\frac{A+B}{2}$?

Comment: Your assumption that there is a minimiser (with the constraints you gave) is wrong. It is not difficult to construct a sequence of functions $v_n$ such that $T(v_n)\to-\infty$. In fact, this is what the Euler-Lagrange result is telling you!

Comment: @bjrone I very much agree with you. How could you explain this "problem" in a formal way?